# Adding validation rule only if all other rules pass, or stop validating entire set of attributes on the first error in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7, customvalidator

I want to allow a user to create a folder on the local storage disk. So the form that is sent to the server quite is simple and has three attributes:

1. **new-folder-name** - that is the name of the folder to be created,
2. **relative-path** - a path to the directory inside which the new directory should be created relative to an **asset** root directory, and
3. **asset_id** - the id of an **asset**, I need this id to get the **asset's** root directory.

The thing is when I validate these attributes I need to also check if the folder the user is going to create already exists. For this purpose I made a rule called `FolderExists`. So, before I run `FolderExists`, I have to be sure all other rules have passed successfully because my custom rule should accept **relative-path** and **asset_id** to be able to build the path to check against.

Here is my `rules()` function, I'm doing validation in custom form request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'asset_id' => ['bail', 'required', 'exists:assets,id'],
        'relative-path' => ['bail', 'required', 'string'],
        'new-folder-name' => ['bail', 'required', 'string', 'min:3', new FolderName, new FolderExists($this->input('asset_id'), $this->input('relative-path')]
    ];
}
```

So my question is:

Is it possible to add `FolderExists` only if all other validation rules pass?

Or maybe it's possible to stop entire validation when the validator encounters first error?

Both options should be fine here.

Thank you!

Comment: look at required_if condition : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: it should be work could not understand why it's failing, are you sure it is failing? and you are getting all three errors while validating instead of one

Comment: @LouisR thank you, but I have checked the docs and especially this point before writing my question here. The docs about `required_if` say "The field under validation must be present and not empty if the __anotherfield__ field is equal to any __value__." I think this is not my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally found the solution myself. Here is what I ended up with.

To achieve the desired result I created another validator in `withValidator()` method of my custom form request, this second validator will handle only the `FolderExists` rule and only if the previous validation fails.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'asset-id' => ['bail', 'required', 'integer', 'exists:assets,id'],
            'relative-path' => ['bail', 'required', 'string'],
            'new-folder-name' => ['bail', 'required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:150', new FolderName]
        ];
    }

public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        if (!$validator->fails())
        {
            $v = Validator::make($this->input(),[
                'new-folder-name' => [new FolderExists($this->input('asset-id'), $this->input('relative-path'))]
            ]);
            $v->validate();
        }
    }
```

If our main validator passes, we make another validator and pass only `FolderExists` rule with its arguments, that have already been validated, and call `validate()` method. That's it.

Comment: Laravel 10+ works